# Do you see "Shared with me" and "Undo Change" feature at your SP2013 (std and enterprise)

Tags: feature

Sorry it maybe a stupid question but in my test environment the titled features are missed.

According to MSDN: 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/manage-document-versions-in-skydrive-pro-HA103158256.aspx
and
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/collaborate-on-documents-in-skydrive-pro-HA102785873.aspx

"Shared with me" and "Undo Change" are equipped for Server 2013 Standard, which is my environment. However I cannot see them anywhere in my test box. It looks to me these two features never exist because no error and no option for them at all.

If you are using SP2013 std or enterprise could you have a look? Thanks.

Comment: I think anyone with SP2013 can help to check it out? I just want to know I am not alone. Microsoft support keep telling me he can see the two features and not willing to look into issue =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem.

Today I applied Language pack service pack 1 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817438 ) for each of my language pack on my test box. I have English (1st install language) and two other language pack installed so I need to download the latter 2 and install.

After patching, I can see "Followed Documents" under "OneDrive" page. Also I can use UNDO CHANGES now.